# troubleshoot sshing to my own computer

Tags: linux, ssh

I have experience ssh'ing to several computers through ubuntu. However for some reason I can't manage to ssh to my own computer (this particular one) from the same machine in the same network. I can ssh other computers to themselves as well, but not this one in particular.

My hostname (different for security reasons is)

```
lab.dept.uni.ece
```

and my accountname is

```
user
```

doing a simple:

```
ssh user@lab.dept.uni.ece
```

should let me ssh to my own computer, but when I type my username and password, it says "permission denied", as if my password (or potentially username ?) is wrong. It's not complaining about the hostname or username, so I'm assuming they are right. Is there any way to check? On the flip side maybe I've setup somesort of sshing block on my computer?

Also, I remember there was a postdoc at my lab who also told me that something funny was going on in my computer since when he wanted to ssh to his account (we created one for him on my computer to see if he could ssh to it with his user/passwd), he actually couldn't.

ssh is installed. How should I go about this?

Output of ssh -vv user@lab.dept.uni.edu

```
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.4, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to lab.dept.uni.edu [128.111.113.132] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.4 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.4
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 86:b8:8e:c5:a5:53:5a:df:26:99:0b:90:9f:4b:91:8e
debug1: Host 'lab.dept.uni.edu' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:9
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: password
user@lab.dept.uni.edu's password: 
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
```

I also thought the username might be an issue since I have a username: 'user' and 'User', where one is lower case and the other uppercase. However it doesn't seem to be the problem since I can't ssh to a new username like 'bob' that I just created where I also know the password.

Comment: Please try again with `ssh -vv user@lab.dept.uni.ece` and add the output to your question. Also, please [edit] and clarify if you're trying to ssh from the same machine, from another on the same network or from outside the network. Finally, are you sure that the user actually exists on the system? Are you using some kind of [LDAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol)? Finally, also clarify whether you're prompted for a password or if you're using private keys.

Comment: updated. I'm prompted with a password and it says it fails. I don't think I'm using some kind of LDAP, I don't think it's the case. It might also be a firewall issue? I created another user and tried to ssh and it failed.

Comment: OK, that does look like your password is wrong. Have you spoken to your IT department? Perhaps you are connecting to a gateway server and you don't have an account there. Or, your server has disabled password connections and needs a private key. I am not an expert on ssh but I doubt this is something we can debug from here. You really should talk to your IT people.

Comment: I talked to them and they can't figure it out either. Do you think re-installing ssh would work?

Comment: Hmm. No, that shouldn't make much difference. Purging it might, I guess. You could try removing all configuration files and reinstalling. You could also try `ssh -vvv` to get even more verbose output, just in case. I stress that I'm no expert though, so take it with a grain of salt. If you don't get an answer here after a while, you could try flagging the question and asking the mods to migrate it to [unix.se] where you'll find more hardcore *nix geeks. Ping me in a couple of days and I can offer a bounty as well (either here or on [unix.se]), I'm also curious.

Comment: Are you sure the password is the correct one? SSHd is asking for a password and the host simply reject it. Contact your system admin if necessary.

Comment: Probably check the ssh directory permissions. Not just the .ssh directory but the parent directory as well.

Comment: @Braiam, yes it is the correct password, becasue even after I create a new account with a new username and password I can't login.

Comment: @Ramesh how do I check the directory permissions, and what variable should I look out for?

Answer (score 2):

You are seeing this from the vantage point of the client, but since you are the owner of the pc you are trying to log into, you can do better than this by starting the *ssh* daemon with the debug option:

```
  service ssh stop
  /usr/sbin/sshd -Dd
```

(*D* prevents the daemon from detaching, *d* puts it in the debug mode). Now you may try logging in from a different pc, and see the output of the daemon, and the reason why it is denying you access.

You should keep in mind that error messages on the *client side* are not meant to be terribly informative, because, apart from legitimate debugging aims, they may be used by malicious attackers to improve their chances of penetration into an unsuspecting victim's computer. On the other hand, debugging messages by the daemon itself are accessible only by the owner of the pc, hence they will be used for legitimate uses. This is why server-side messages are more informative.

Hopefully, this will give you/us enough info to debug the problem at the next iteration.

Comment: In the end, tech support managed to fix the problem for me. Apparently the issue was that I didn't add the permissions in a specific ssh file for users allowed to ssh to that computer.